# Edit bootstrap Modal Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, laravel-8, edit

I'm using Laravel 8 and bootstrap modal to edit a modal,
I'm trying to update "courrier", when I press the buttom "Modifier", the modal shows, but The data doesn't get updated, I didn't get it!

Here is my listeCourriersBog.blade.php page:

```
          @section('scripts')

            <script type="text/javascript">
                @if ((count($errors) > 0) and (session("NON")) )
                    $('#ModalCreate').modal('show');
                @endif
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                @if ((count($errors) > 0) and (session("NO")) )
                    $("#ModalEdit{{$courrier->id}}").modal('show');
                @endif
            </script>

            @endsection




            @section('contenu')

            <div class="x_panel">
              <div class="x_title">
                <h2>Liste des courriers</h2>
                <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                  <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                  </li>
                  
                  
                </ul>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="x_content">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="card-box table-responsive">
                <p class="text-muted font-13 m-b-30">
                <a href="#" class="buttonPrevious buttonDisabled btn btn-primary" data-                                                                    
                 toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalCreate"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  
                  Ajouter un nouveau courrier</a>
                  <br>
                 <!-- <a href="{{ route('ajoutCourrier') }}" class="buttonPrevious 
                   buttonDisabled btn btn-primary">Ajouter un nouveau courrier</a>
                  <br>
                 -->

                  <b style=""> Nombre total de courriers
                  <span class="badge badge-danger"> {{count($courriers)}}</span>
                  <br>

                  @if(session("courrier_created")) 
                               
                                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible " 
                                 role="alert">
                                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" 
                                  aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                                  </button>
                                  <strong></strong> Le courrier a été ajouté avec succès.
                                </div>
                  @endif
                  

                  @if(session("courrier_updated")) 
                               
                               <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible " 
                                  role="alert">
                                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" 
                                 aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                                 </button>
                                 <strong></strong> Le courrier a été mis à jour avec succès.
                               </div>
                 @endif
                
                </p>
                
                <table id="datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt- 
                    responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Bog</th>
                      
                      <th>Référence du courrier</th>
                      <th>Type du courrier</th>
                      <th>Expediteur</th>
                      
                      <th>Date du courrier</th>
                      <th>Date d'arrivée</th>
                      <th>Actions</th>
                      <th>Objet</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    
                  @foreach($courriers as $key => $courrier)
                   
                    <tr>
                    @if($courrier['Type']['type_lib'] == 'Ordinaire')
                      <td>{{ $courrier->bog_ord }}</td>
                    @endif  
                    @if($courrier['Type']['type_lib'] == 'Interne')
                      <td>{{ $courrier->bog_int }}</td>
                    @endif 
                    @if($courrier['Type']['type_lib'] == 'Wilaya')
                      <td>{{ $courrier->bog_wil }}</td>
                    @endif 
                    @if($courrier['Type']['type_lib'] == 'Ministere')
                      <td>{{ $courrier->bog_min }}</td>
                    @endif 
                    @if($courrier['Type']['type_lib'] == 'Daira/Apc')
                      <td>{{ $courrier->bog_da }}</td>
                    @endif 
                    @if($courrier['Type']['type_lib'] == 'Avenant')
                      <td>{{ $courrier->bog_av }}</td>
                    @endif 
                    
                      <td>{{ $courrier->courrier_num }}</td>
                      <td> {{ $courrier['Type']['type_lib'] }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $courrier->expediteur }}</td>
                      
                      <td>{{ $courrier->date_courrier }}</td>
                      <td> {{ $courrier->created_at }}</td>
                      <td>
                      @if($courrier->sdg_num == '')
                      <a class="" href="{{ route('modifierCourrierPost', $courrier->id) }}" 
                   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalEdit{{$courrier->id}}">
                      <span class="badge badge-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> 
                      Modifier</span>

                      </a>
                      
                      @else
                      <span class="badge badge-success">Transmis</span>
                      @endif
                     

                      </td>
                      <td> {{ $courrier->objet }}</td>


                      @include('MODAL.edit') 
                    </tr>

                    @endforeach
                 
               
                   
                    
                  </tbody>
                </table>

                
              </div>
      </div>
```

And my edit.blade.php modal:

```
         <form action="{{ route('modifierCourrierPost', $courrier->id) }}" method="post"                           
              enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf

            
             <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="ModalEdit{{$courrier->id}}" 
                      tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                  <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Mettre à jour le courrier</h4>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria- 
                         hidden="true">×</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        @if(session("NO")) 
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible " role="alert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- 
                               label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                            <strong>Courrier non valide!</strong> {{ session("NO")}}
                        </div>
                        @endif
                    

                        <div class="field item form-group">
                            <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3  label- 
                           align">Référence du courrier<span class="required"></span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control @if($errors- 
                         >has('courrier_num')) is-invalid @endif" value="{{ 
                             $courrier['courrier_num'] }}" name="courrier_num" data-validate- 
                           length-range="5,15" >
                                @if($errors->has("courrier_num"))                                             
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first("courrier_num") }} 
                                         </strong>
                                        </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="field item form-group">
                            <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3  label-align">Type 
                            du courrier<span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <select class="form-control" value="{{ $courrier['type_id'] 
                                  }}" name="type_id">
                                    <option></option>
                                    @foreach($type_lib as $type)
                                    <option value="{{$type->id}}" {{($type->id == $courrier- 
                                        >type_id ) ? 'selected' : '' }}>  {{$type->type_lib}} 
                                    </option> 
                                    @endforeach
                                            
                                    
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                   
                                  
                        <div class="field item form-group">
                            <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3  label- 
                         align">Objet<span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <textarea class="form-control @if($errors->has('objet')) is- 
                                invalid @endif" name="objet">{{ $courrier['objet']  }} 
                                </textarea>
                                    @if($errors->has("objet"))                                             
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first("objet") }}</strong>
                                        </div>
                                    @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="field item form-group">
                            <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3  label- 
                        align">Expéditeur<span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <input class="form-control @if($errors->has('expediteur')) is- 
                       invalid @endif" value="{{ $courrier['expediteur'] }}" type="text" 
                        name="expediteur" data-validate-linked="email" >
                                    @if($errors->has("expediteur"))                                             
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first("expediteur") }} 
                                   </strong>
                                        </div>
                                    @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                                   
                        <div class="field item form-group">
                            <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3  label-align">Date 
                        du courrier<span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <input class="form-control @if($errors->has('date_courrier')) 
                            is-invalid @endif " value="{{ $courrier['date_courrier'] }}" 
                            type="text" data-date-format="d-m-Y" name="date_courrier" 
                           required="required">
                                    @if($errors->has("date_courrier"))                                             
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first("date_courrier") }} 
                                            </strong>
                                        </div>
                                    @endif

                            </div>
                        </div>



                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
                         dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Modifier</button>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
           
       
          </form>
```

I tried to put the edit modal in the listeCourriersBog.blade.php but when I click, only the last courrier get updated!
Don't know how to fix that